# JQuery UI slider, only the Button loads and not the Range and the slider does not slide

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am using the jquery slider, the issue that I face is only the slider button is displayed and not the range. When I try to slide the button, then it does not slide.

HTML

```
<div id="slider-range"></div>
```

JS

```
$("#slider-range").slider({
  range: true,
  min: 0,
  max: 500,
  values: [75, 300],
  slide: function (event, ui) {
    console.log("sliding");
  }
});
```

After this is how the UI comes up
[image: Slider button without range]

Notes:

1. I confirmed the div gets loaded before the execution of JS and there is no exception in the console.
2. To confirm the load of JQuery UI JS and CSS, I rendered a different control(Calendar Control) in the same Div, and it loaded and worked properly.
3. I implemented the slider call back to confirm that the control works from JQueryUI, and the slider call back works properly. I am able to see the Console log that I have put in the callback.
4. I confirmed through the Elements tab in Console that the Div has been appended with JQueryUI classes[image: JQuery UI classes]
5. I observed that there is a href attribute added to the slider button, this points to localhost.
6. I have also, confirmed that through the console I can see the jquery-UI styles being applied on the slider button [image: Styles being applied for JQuery-UI]

It would be very helpful if someone can help me through this.

Comment: did you wrap the call in a document.ready?  might help even though you suggest there is no order of operations concern

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The images suggest you have not included the CSS for jQuery. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: you dont have neccessary dependencies .....

Comment: @nikhilsugandh: It would be very helpful, if you can suggest whats the missing dependencies

Comment: @Ctznkane525: I didnot wrap it in document.ready, but I confirmed the same through console just before the code to add the control in JS and document is available, even the div where I am adding the control is also available.
Also, by inspecting the element I confirmed that the div has been appended with the elements of the control

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

https://jsfiddle.net/6sxg9ytd/1/

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Slider - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider(
    {
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 500,
    values: [ 55, 105 ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
    console.log("sliding");
    }
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="slider"></div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code piece is similar to what is available on the jqueryui.com. I have already tried that and that does not work. 
Also, can you please explain what is the use of demo/style.css and how does it work for you. As per my understanding this is the one needed for jquiryui page. Since, you are using a different environment, does it solve any purpose

Comment: @RishabhNigam check the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6sxg9ytd/1/
its working..you can guve the answer a green tick...

Comment: @RishabhNigam you can give it a green tick. check the fiddle link in the answer